# Metamask Transaction does not appear in Ganache

Tags: truffle, metamask, ganache

I'm trying to call the storeQueryResults() function of my smart contract in the following way:

```
storeInput: function(event) {
    var queryResultHandlerinstance;

    App.contracts.QueryResultHandler.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      queryResultHandlerinstance = instance;
      return queryResultHtandlerinstance.storeQueryResults(1, 2, "a", "b", {
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
      });
    }).then(function(result) {
      alert("success");
    }).catch(function(err) {
      alert(err.message);
    });
  },
};
```

Then, after confirming the transaction in Metamask, I can see it is approved there:[image: Metamask_printscreen]

However, in Ganache nothing happens: [image: Ganache_printscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have figured it out. Temporarily, I removed MetaMask and tried it out by only using Ganache. Then, I got a proper error message saying that the transaction exceeds the gas limit. Therefore, I added 'gas: 3000000' as a parameter, so my transaction looks like this:

```
App.contracts.QueryResultHandler.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    queryResultHandlerinstance = instance;

    return queryResultHandlerinstance.storeQueryResults(1, 2, "a", "b", {
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
        gas: 3000000
    });
}).then(function(result) {
    alert("success");
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
  alert(err.message);
});
```

So, as a takeaway, I don't think that MetaMask returns errors properly and explicitly defining the gas limit is important.

Answer (score -2):

I also have difficulty viewing transactions under the Transactions tab within Ganache.  Can you see the transaction under the Logs tab?